# Getting s3 key name within EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-emr

I'm running a `hvie` script on `EMR` that's pulling data out of `s3` keys.  I can get all the data and put it in a table just fine.  The problem is, some of the data I need is in the key name.  How do I get the key name from within `hive` and put that into the `hive` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced similar problem recently. From what I researched, it depends. You can get the data out of the "directory" part but not the "filename" part of s3 keys.

You can use `partition` if s3 keys are formatted properly. `partition` can be queried the same way as columns. here is a link with some examples: [Loading data with Hive, S3, EMR, and Recover Partitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13319080/loading-data-with-hive-s3-emr-and-recover-partitions)

You can also specify the partitions yourself if s3 files are already grouped properly. For example I needed the date information so my script looked like this:

```
create external table Example(Id string, PostalCode string, State string)
    partitioned by (year int, month int, day int) 
    row format delimited fields terminated by ',' 
    tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1");

alter table Example add partition(year=2014,month=8,day=1) location 's3n://{BuckeyName}/myExampledata/2014/08/01/';

alter table Example add partition(year=2014,month=8,day=2) location 's3n://{BuckeyName}/myExampledata/2014/08/02/';
...keep going
```

The `partition` data must be part of the "directory name" and not the "filename" because Hive loads data from a directory.

If you need to read some text out of the file name, I think you have to create custom program to rename the objects to so that the text you need is in the "directory name".

Good luck!